# rviz: unsaved changes

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to somehow prevent rviz from asking to save unsaved changes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45885/rviz:-unsaved-changes/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-10-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no direct way to do this, but fell free to write a patch :) You are not the only one annoyed be this popup.

Good practise is not to close rviz at all, only after work with the robot. If you need to restart rviz for some reason, it means there is something wrong with your code or rviz itself (happens too). I use to close rviz from time to time when I am working on battery, it saves some power (opengl likes my cpu).

As a workaround:

- ctrl+s and alt+f4 to speed things up, or
- alt+tab and ctrl+c, when you don't want changes to be saved

I don't know of any better solution.

---

Originally posted by [kszonek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2959/kszonek/) with karma: 459 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with @kszonek and your question, it would be nice to be able to turn off this feature.  Perhaps a patch is in order.

My workaround is to always add `rviz` to my launch files, as well as a launch argument to not start it if I don't want.  Then I find that when I kill the launch process, `rviz` closes without asking to save, even if its settings have changed.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1